# Linux Speeding Up /etc/resolv.conf's search domain Function

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a company intranet, which has two subnets and two associated DNS domains, the Ubuntu box is in the first subnet. I want to be able to use the short names for hosts, not the FQDN, on both subnets. So lets say the DNS domains are subnet1.com (192.168.1.0/24) and subnet2.com (192.168.2.0/24), I have:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 192.168.2.2
search subnet1.com subnet2.com
```

in `/etc/resolv.conf`. My machine is `linux.subnet1.com` and there are two other machines box a and b on each subnet. So if I do `ssh boxa` all is good, but when I do `ssh boxb` there is a lengthy delay while it tries `boxb.subnet1.com` first before trying `boxb.subnet2.com` and eventually succeeding.

When I do the same thing on Windows there is an initial delay like with Linux but then it remembers what worked and the next time it's instant.

Is there a way of drastically speeding this up or caching the result on Linux?

On the actual box I am using dnsmasq for caching and it then consults those 2 upstream DNS servers in turn. However dnsmasq only ever gets to see the FQDNs as the resolver uses the search list to fully qualify short hostname queries and so unless there is some sort of whacky dnsmasq setting that says `ok ignore the given domain and do a wild card match just using the hostname part' then presumably the solution lies within the resolver.

I've searched and searched but not found any reference to how to speed up the search list in the resolver or cache previous results so as to avoid future delays.

Comment: Why _is_ there a lengthy delay? Negative DNS replies should be as fast as positive ones. Is one of your nameservers reacting badly when queried for domains it doesn't recognize? (Dnsmasq's split-dns support might help with that.)

Comment: @user1686 You're spot on, one of them is very slow. I also had no-negcache turned on in dnsmasq to get around a lesser issue and so the result wasn't cached. Removing that option is by far the lesser of the two evils. MANY THANKS. If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Being on an intranet and never having to need a search setting for more than one domain previously, I was unfamiliar with the expected timeouts etc as DNS server failure timeouts can be quite lengthy and so it didn't seem unreasonable that an unknown FQDN would take time to fail. However this shouldn't be the case.

First issue was a slow DNS server or one failing to correctly respond with a not know message. Second issue was the fact that in my dnsmasq config I had enabled the `no-negcache` option to get around an issue of FQDNs coming and going and changing due to VMs on VMware vSphere coming and going etc. However this is much less of an issue than the delay mentioned above as one can always flush the cache. Once that change was made the behaviour was exactly the same as on Windows.